# Tweak htaccess file to map a folder name to an actual folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to mask the path of a folder using htaccess file.

So on the server I have this real folder called `mydata` which contains many php files and subfolders.

When I retrieve data from this folder, in php or html files, I want to write the path as `somedata`, instead of `mydata`; for example:
`/somedata/mydatafile.php` instead of `/mydata/mydatafile.php`.
So the `mydata` folder name will be always hidden from users for security reasons.    `somedata` is just a name, there isn't an actual folder on the server.

I have a few addon domains beside the main domain, and the same `mydata` folder exists on each add-on domain too.
The structure in cPanel is:

```
/public_html/mysite.com/mydata
/mysite2.com/mydata
/mysite3.com/mydata
```

where `mysite.com` is the main domain and the others are addons.

The htaccess file should map `somedata` folder name to `mydata` folder name, in any path in any domain and addon-domain,
so I would place it in the root  (is root considered where `public_html`, `mysite2.com` and `mysite3.com` sites are?)
I prefer to do it without redirect, the simplest way possible for the server.

With RewriteEngine On, I tried the following:

1.

```
Alias /somedata /mydata
```

2.

```
RewriteRule ^mydata/(.*)$ /somedata/$1 [NC,L]
```

3.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somedata
RewriteRule .* /mydata/ [NC,L]
```

I'm stuck because of the syntax, can we make at least one work...?

Answer (score 0):

Your second try is close, but you have the arguments backwards:

```
RewriteRule ^somedata/(.*)$ /mydata/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried like that but for some reason it seems not to work.
Why would't it work?

Comment: @Windranger Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file? Also, where is your htaccess file? Is it in the root directory?

Comment: There are no other directives in htaccess file now.
The code is just:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/somedata/(.*)$ $1/mydata/$2 [NC,L]

I tried with htaccess file both in root and in individual sites.
I use the same code in each of the sites:
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 include ($path . '/somefolder/header.php');


When I place it in the root of a site, say mysite2.com, if I print the above path, I get
/home/userid/mysite2.com/somefolder/header.php
same result if I place it one level higher, in the root.

Comment: @Windranger That’s the problem. You changed the `RewriteRule`. That one will match `/folder/somedata/folder` but not `/somedata/folder`.